# Group by missing or invalid. FoxPro 9

Tags: sql, foxpro, oledbconnection

I am using OLEDB accessing FoxPro DBF files and keep getting a `SQL: GROUP BY clause is missing or invalid.` error when adding another field to the `SELECT` command.

This works fine...

```
SELECT SUM(qty_shipd) AS total, item_no FROM arline 
WHERE invc_date >= {7/25/2018} AND invc_date <= {10/23/2018} 
GROUP BY item_no ORDER BY total DESC
```

When i try to add the description field, I get the error...

```
SELECT SUM(qty_shipd) AS total, item_no, print_desc FROM arline 
WHERE invc_date >= {7/25/2018} AND invc_date <= {10/23/2018} 
GROUP BY item_no, print_desc ORDER BY total DESC
```

Why would I get an error adding another field?

Comment: Does `arline` have a `print_desc` column?  Are you certain the new column is in both the `SELECT` list and the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Yes, it exists in the arline.dbf file, and it is in both the select and the group by.

Comment: FWIW with dates you're probably safer using an unambiguous format, i.e. {^2017-07-25}

Comment: The print_desc field (column) cannot be of type Memo, General, or Blob - is that the case?

Comment: @AlanB - you should post that as an answer!  It identified my issue, thanks 